# IntelliSense incomplete in some cases

Tags: visual-studio-2012

There may be other cases, but this is the first one that I've seen.

`System.Resources.ResourceManager` is missing a part of the IntelliSense. For example, `GetString` is missing. Typing `GetString(` won't give IntelliSense. Hovering over it shows information.

[image: ResourceManager member list]
[image: GetString hover]

Things I've tried:

- Restart Visual Studio
- Reset all environment settings
- Delete the content of `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas`
- Execute `devenv /resetuserdata`

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug and IntelliSense displays what you requested.

You need to create an instance of the ResourceManager to get the methods like GetString or GetObject, cause these are instance methods.

Currently you access the class `ResourceManager` and therefore IntelliSense only lists the static members.

Comment: Correct. I read over a sample too quickly, and the info displayed on hover only added to my confusion.