# Incomplete list of properties/methods in IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

I am using VB.NET in Visual Studio Community 2017. I noticed that in some cases the list of available properties and methods for an object is incomplete.

One example can be seen here:
[image]

As depicted, I want to use the `RowCount` property of the `dgv` object, that is of type `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`. You can see, that right above it the property is there and working fine, I can just type it by hand. It just takes a second or two, before the background compiler (for lack of better term) acknowledges it as correct. The behavior messes up the typing flow, since often IntelliSense autocorrects what it perceives as typos.

**Note:** This is not exclusive to the shown property. I noticed it for other examples, and also in function calls and other random places, but I could not find a clear methodology of what is missing and what isn't.

Looking around I found e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079773/intellisense-incomplete-in-some-cases), however it deals with a completely different problem.

Is this just a bug in Visual Studio (and if so, is it reported somewhere?), can someone confirm this, and does someone know of a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Albano Gheller posted an answer on the [Visual Studio Community page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/48556/vs-2017-vb-the-intellisense-for-the-datagridview-c.html).

To quote him and the required step for a fix:

```
I've fixed the problem in this way:

1. I've exported my settings from Tool - Import/Export settings
2. I've set the property HideAdvancedMembers = true inside
   <ToolsOptionsSubCategory name="Basic" RegisteredName="Basic" PackageName="Text Management Package">
   because C# has true and works
3. I've imported this modified settings.
```

So to summarize:

Find the part: `<PropertyValue name="HideAdvancedMembers">false</PropertyValue>` in the exported settings document's `Basic` ToolsOptionsSubCategory. 
Change this to `<PropertyValue name="HideAdvancedMembers">true</PropertyValue>`, save, and then reimport the settings.

I don't know why hiding members leads to showing more members, but whatever ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Followed your steps and I got the same result like yours, I already reported this issue to the VS Product Team, please check this: [VS 2017--VB: the intellisense for the DataGridView control not works like VS 2015](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/48556/vs-2017-vb-the-intellisense-for-the-datagridview-c.html), you can vote it or add a comment, then we need to waiting for the confirmation from the VS Product Team, thank you for your feedback.
[image]
Meanwhile, I tried it in C#>Windows Forms application and the intellisense works fine just like the VS 2015.

Comment: Good to have an independent confirmation. Maybe you can add to the report, that it is not an isolated problem with the datagridview control. I'll see that I collect further examples when I stumble upon them.

Comment: @Jens, if you find any more control, please feel free to let me know, I will update that thread to make VS Product Team to know it, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Another example is the `ClientRectangle` property on any control, e.g. `Button1.ClientRectangle`

Comment: @Jens, thank you for your update and I tested it on my side, then added a comment with this property to the above thread, waiting for the confirmation come from the VS Product Team Engineers.

Comment: The `Graphics.FromHwnd` function is one more, that is not a Control.

Comment: A shame they closed it instead of dealing with it. Time to upgrade I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In supplement to Jens answer/to save anyone else some work:

- Take the following XML, which is the minimum set of settings required to flip the problem attribute:

```xml
<UserSettings>
    <ApplicationIdentity version="15.0"/>
    <ToolsOptions>
        <ToolsOptionsCategory RegisteredName="TextEditor" name="TextEditor">
            <ToolsOptionsSubCategory PackageName="Text Management Package" RegisteredName="Basic" name="Basic">
                <PropertyValue name="HideAdvancedMembers">true</PropertyValue>
            </ToolsOptionsSubCategory>
        </ToolsOptionsCategory>
    </ToolsOptions>
</UserSettings>
```

- Save it on the desktop in a file called `a.vssettings`
- Go to **Tools.. Import and Export Settings**
- Choose **Import**
- Choose **No, just import**
- Browse for the file you saved, do **Next**, **Finish**

I presume that there's a bug in VS where they got the boolean logic upside down for the intellisense, and advanced members are hidden when this attrib is false and shown when it's true