# VB.NET RowCount not an accessible property of DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Making an app that uses virtual mode DGV.  I cannot access the property RowCount of DataGridView, the IDE does not show it as a valid property.  MSDN says it is.  Using Visual Studio 2017 and .NET 4.5.2

Here is my code.  I'm just going to post it as is, because I need every line.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports HelperLib.SQLiteModule
Imports System.Data.SQLite

Public Class ProxyTesterView

    Private connString As String = "Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/data.db3;" & "Version=3;"

    Public Property ProxyDT As DataTable

    Private Sub ProxyTesterView_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Only load proxies if we are not in Design mode!
        If DesignMode = False Then
            Try
                LoadProxiesFromDB()
            Catch ex As SQLite.SQLiteException
                If ex.ErrorCode = 1 Then
                    'DB Doesn't exist, create it!
                    CreateNewDB()
                End If
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateNewDB()
        Dim sql As String = "CREATE TABLE proxies(ip VARCHAR(15), port VARCHAR(5), valid BOOLEAN, speed VARCHAR(5), countryName VARCHAR(36), PRIMARY KEY (ip, port))"
        CreateDB(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "/data.db3", sql)
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadProxiesFromDB()
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT ip, port, valid, speed, countryName FROM proxies"
        ProxyDT = GetDataTableFromDB(connString, sql)

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddProxyToDB(proxy As Proxy)
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO proxies (ip, port, valid, speed, countryName) VALUES (@ip, @port, @valid, @speed, @countryName)")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", proxy.IP)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@port", proxy.Port)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valid", proxy.IsValid)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@speed", proxy.Speed)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countryName", proxy.Country)

            ExecuteNonQuery(connString, cmd)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProxyTesterView_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
            For Each proxy As Proxy In GetProxiesFromClipboard()
                ProxyDT.Rows.Add(proxy)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetProxiesFromClipboard() As List(Of Proxy)
        Dim proxies As New List(Of Proxy)
        For Each line As String In Clipboard.GetText().Split(vbCrLf)
            'Regular Expression for proxy pattern found here: https://superuser.com/questions/582120/regex-pattern-for-proxy
            If Regex.IsMatch(line, "((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}):(\d+)") Then
                proxies.Add(New Proxy(line))
            End If
        Next
        Return proxies
    End Function

    Private Sub dgvProxies_CellValueNeeded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs) Handles dgvProxies.CellValueNeeded
        Dim row As DataRow = ProxyDT.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Select Case dgvProxies.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
            Case "ip"
                e.Value = row.Item("ip")
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `Rows.Count`...

Comment: @Zaggler It's ReadOnly.  And not the property I am referring to in my question.  I need to set RowCount to have CellValueNeeded fire since I am using virtual mode...

Comment: Ah, you said you couldnt access it. I thought you just wanted a count... Where are you using this or trying to use this, i dont see where you are?

Comment: What error gives you when trying to set `RowCount`?

Comment: @Zaggler I can understand the confusion, but I can't access the property RowCount, like my question says.  Not Rows.Count :)  Thanks though.

Comment: Change the framework to 4... do you get it?

Comment: @Pikoh The IDE doesn't let me even select it as a property of DataGridView using Intellisense.  It kept auto correcting RowCount to DisplayedRowCount function, which obviously wasn't what I was looking for.  No clue why intellisense says the property doesn't exist, when it does.  Despite this major annoyance it seems to actually build fine if I just ignore intellisense.  I guess this is a new feature for VS2017...

Comment: You also have this namespace right `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: Ok..See [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/48556/vs-2017-vb-the-intellisense-for-the-datagridview-c.html). There's a bug ticket opened. Also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43603438/579895)